# Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using XAMPP Server 1.7.7

While opening the php file, i receive the error

`Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor'` not found

Comment: Interesting. Do you also have a question? ;-)

Comment: PHP Was not compiled with XSL or it is not included in php.ini.  See: [XSL Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Install the XSL extension to get that class. This might be as easy as uncommenting (remove the starting ';') on the line that reads `extension=php_xsl.dll` in php.ini on Windows, or `apt-get install php5-xsl` on most Linux-based systems. For custom builds of PHP, use configure option `--with-xsl` (requires package libxslt1-dev).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I really should have Googled it....still ticked as answer.

Comment: It is exactly `extension=php_xsl.dll` trying to find it using `Ctrl+F` made me realize it. A minor Typo.

Comment: Also make sure extension_dir is set correctly - "extension_dir = ext" worked for me on Windows PHP5.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache after installing this

Answer (score 5):

Its necessary install the XLS extension.

My solution by my context.

I'm using one docker container contain ubuntu base and using php-fpm (ie if you simply already use linux ubuntu in the same).

The steps to install this extension in my context were:

First search xsl extension on linux repository

`sudo apt-cache search xsl`

I ended up finding the php5-xsl, so it was only install

`sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`

that the installation process the setup configuration is already added, if does not happen, just make yourself

`sudo vim /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini`

insert this content:
`extension=xsl.so`

(obviously the paths are according to your php configuration settings, but my example is the default configuration)

Restart you php fpm and done (`sudo service php5-fpm restart`)!